# Convert Latitude,Longitude to iframe link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, iframe, location

Im currently working on a project that requires me to fetch the users current location & save it in DB. Later display it in a GoogleMap

I'm saving the users location using Latitude and Longitude. 
I'm able to create a link which redirects to maps using this data, but I'm not able to use it to generate a iframe link.

*For Example:*
**LAT:** 13.033419  **LNG:** 77.563976

Making a link in this fashion(Can use this on a btn):

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=13.033419,77.563976
```

Wish to use this LAT & LNG data to generate this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3887.035379846286!2d77.56178731437602!3d13.03341899081541!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zMTPCsDAyJzAwLjMiTiA3N8KwMzMnNTAuMyJF!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1483076445133" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This bit to be precise:
**pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3887.035379846286!2d77.56178731437602!3d13.03341899081541!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zMTPCsDAyJzAwLjMiTiA3N8KwMzMnNTAuMyJF!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1483076445133**

Please lemme know if there is a way we can achieve this.
Even an alternate method of doing the same is appreciated if any :)

Comment: so do you want to show the users location on an iframe using the lattitude and the longitude? Also I want to know how you wish to generate the data using the lattitude and the longitude `pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3887.035379846286!2d77.56178731437602!3d13.03341899081541!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zMTPCsDAyJzAwLjMiTiA3N8KwMzMnNTAuMyJF!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1483076445133`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this should solve your issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.7" data-semver="1.5.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="googleControllerTest">
      <iframe ng-src="{{url}}" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>

--- Code
angular.module('app', [

  ]).controller('googleControllerTest', function($scope, $sce, $interpolate){

    $scope.data = {
      lat: 13.033419,
      long: 77.563976
    }
    $scope.value = $interpolate("https://maps.google.com/maps?q={{lat}},{{long}}&hl=es;z=14&output=embed")($scope.data);
    $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.value)
  })
```

Plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/2o7WPnBbJZpk17bsyRyG?p=preview

Comment: Is there a vanilla JS implementation of this answer?